# Rock and metal albums recorded with symphony orchestras

Tags: bands

I am looking for **rock** and **metal** bands who recorded albums with real orchestras. Examples:

- Scorpions And Berliner Philharmoniker - Moment Of Glory (2000)
- Within Temptation and Metropole Orchestra - Black Symphony (2008)
- Metallica with The San Francisco Symphony - S&M (Symphony and Metallica)

---

I know that "rock" and "metal" are very wide genres of music, but I think I don't have to be very specyfic because there are not so many albums like this and I think I like all kinds of rock.

I'm a bit new on this part of StackExchange network, so if something is wrong with my question please don't downvote my question too hard.

Comment: Could you give your thoughts about what people answered below?

Answer (score 3):

Quite a bit older, but I would include:

> The Moody Blues with the London Festival Orchestra - [***Days of Future Passed***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_Future_Passed) (1967)

Answer (score 3):

And other old ones:

- Procol Harum: Live with the Edmonton Symphony Orchestra
- Deep Purple: Concerto for Group and Orchestra